# IS the sequence right?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

[image]

What i think is that, the sequence isn't correctly formulated.

I have tried like this **7x5-9=35**

**2x3-1=5**

**8x6-4=44**

**4x5-9=?=11**

Comment: My understanding: multiply the two largest and subtract the square of the smallest. Hence, 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern which exist is given $a<b<c$ three integers which are all different, the value in the middle is $b\times c - a^2$

Comment: oppps! Got it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
\begin{align*}
26 &= 7\times 5 -3^2 \\
5 &= 2\times 3-1^2 \\
44 &= 8\times 6-2^2
\end{align*}